# DB2 SQL update using 3 tables, update 1, join with 2 more to select rows to update

Tags: sql, join, db2

I'm working with 3 tables. Based on the contents of 1 or more fields in each table, I need to update 1 of the tables with constant data. My select works great to discover how many records will need to be updated, but I can't seem to get the update to work.  I co-worker, with more DB2 SQL experience, sent me code to try.  His runs without error, but doesn't get the join and 'where' conditions correct to update only the needed records - it is updating way too many records.

Here is the select that is working correctly:

```
select *
    from mylib.tabcp
inner join mylib.tabc c on cpactnum = c.actnum
inner join mylib.tabt t on cpactnum = t.actnum and cptagid = t.tagid
where (cpstatus = 'Active' and t.tagsts = 'P' and (c.actsts = 'A' or c.actsts = 'D'))
```

tabcp has these fields:  cpactnum    cpstatus   cptagid

tabc has:  actnum    actsts

tabt has:  actnum  tagid tagsts

I need to update some fields in tabcp when:  tabcp status is active, tabc status is A or D and tabt status is P

Here is the update my co-worker gave me - it runs, doesn't get any errors, but doesn't correctly select the records to update.

```
update tabcp
set cpstatus = 'Inactive',
    cpdelstamp = current_timestamp,
    cpdeldate = current_date,
    cpdeltime = current_time,
    cpdeluser = current_user
where cpstatus = 'Active'
and cpactnum in 
 (select e.cpactnum from tabcp e
    inner join tabc c on e.cpactnum = c.actnum
    inner join tabt k on e.cpactnum = k.actnum
                     and e.cptagid = k.tagid
 where c.actsts in ('A','D') and k.tagsts = 'P')
```

I am too unfamiliar with DB2 SQL updating.  I've tried various changes and, thus far, I just haven't gotten the 'combination' correct.

Can anyone help me, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE mylib.tabcp p
set cpstatus = 'Inactive',
    cpdelstamp = current_timestamp,
    cpdeldate = current_date,
    cpdeltime = current_time,
    cpdeluser = current_user
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
FROM mylib.tabc c, mylib.tabt t
WHERE
p.cpactnum = c.actnum
and p.cpactnum = t.actnum and p.cptagid = t.tagid
and p.cpstatus = 'Active' and t.tagsts = 'P' and c.actsts in ('A', 'D')
)
```

Comment: Thank you Mark.  This worked great.  I so very much appreciate the help.  I'm going to 'study' this to hopefully understand just how these queries are processing.   Again, thank you ...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
enter code here
update tp
set cpstatus = 'Inactive',
cpdelstamp = current_timestamp,
cpdeldate = current_date,
cpdeltime = current_time,
cpdeluser = CURRENT_USER
from mylib.tabcp tp  
where cpstatus = 'Active'
and cpactnum in 
(select e.cpactnum from tabcp e
inner join tabc c on e.cpactnum = c.actnum
inner join tabt k on e.cpactnum = k.actnum
                 and e.cptagid = k.tagid
where c.actsts in ('A','D') and k.tagsts = 'P')
```

Comment: Thank you Hosein - however this code received the following error:                               
[SQL0199] Keyword FROM not expected. Valid tokens: USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER WHERE OFFSET. Cause . . . . . : The keyword FROM was not expected here. A syntax error was detected at keyword FROM. The partial list of valid tokens is USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH LIMIT ORDER WHERE OFFSET. This list assumes that the statement is correct up to the unexpected keyword. The error may be earlier in the statement but the syntax of the statement seems to be valid up to this point.